# Copy files to a Laptop

Tags: file-transfer

I have an urgent requirement to copy files from one laptop to another laptop which are not connected in any way.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: use external hard disk

Comment: Logicaly, if they are not connected IN ANY WAY, you will never be able to copy files between them.  More info please.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some ideas, what if any work for you depends on what you're willing to do.

1. laplink type connection(with laplink s/w)
2. mini-network via ethernet (desktop &laptop)
3. USB port network
4. flash drives
5. burn to DVD or CD
6. use www service to FTP data
7. use ext. HD via USB or firewire

These do work, but again it depnds on s/w or h/w and/or purchases you need to get.

Comment: 8) WiFi in ad-hoc mode

Answer (score 3):

I believe the fastest way to copy files is to connect them directly using Ethernet cable. Second option I'd choose is to use external USB hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

If they are newish machines then a direct connection via an ethernet cable will work fine - if the light comes on at both ends then you are fine.  If it does not then you will need to use a cross-over cable or 2 cables and a network hub such as your broadband router.

Once you have a connection you can just share a folder or dirve from one to another using windows file sharing - look in network neighbourhood for the other machine.

C.

Answer (score 1):

If both machines are connected to the Internet, you can use Gmail.

See the [GMail Ddrive shell extension](http://www.viksoe.dk/code/gmail.htm):

> GMail Drive is a Shell Namespace
>   Extension that creates a virtual
>   filesystem around your Google Mail
>   account, allowing you to use Gmail as
>   a storage medium.

[image]

Comment: That would take *a looong time* ...

Answer (score 1):

I'd set up an adhoc wireless network between them then copy that way. You'll get 54Mbps transfer rate if they are close, which depending on the amount of data you are sending may or may not be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of methods are mentioned in other posts, the two I'd chose are to create a small network (crossover or ad-hoc wireless), or to use an external hard disk.

As a last resort - take the hard drives out of both laptops, connect them to another machine (using a usb bridge if needed), and copy the file from there.